# Find the indices of the lowest closest neighbors between two lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given 2 numpy arrays of unequal size: A (a presorted dataset) and B (a list of query values). I want to find the closest "lower" neighbor in array A to each element of array B. Example code below:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0.456, 2.0, 2.948, 3.0, 7.0, 12.132]) #pre-sorted dataset
B = np.array([1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 5.0, 7.0]) #query values, not necessarily sorted
print A.searchsorted(B)
# RESULT:  [1 1 2 4 4]
# DESIRED: [0 0 1 3 4]
```

In this example, B[0]'s closest neighbors are A[0] and A[1]. It is closest to A[1], which is why searchsorted returns index 1 as a match, but what i want is the lower neighbor at index 0. Same for B[1:4], and B[4] should be matched with A[4] because both values are identical.

I could do something clunky like this:

```
desired = []
for b in B:
    id = -1
    for a in A:
        if a > b:
            if id == -1:
                desired.append(0)
            else:
                desired.append(id)
            break

        id+=1

print desired
# RESULT: [0, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

But there's gotta be a prettier more concise way to write this with numpy. I'd like to keep my solution in numpy because i'm dealing with large data sets, but i'm open to other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce the optional argument `side` and set it to `'right'` as mentioned in the [`docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Then, subtract the final indices result by `1` for the desired output, like so -

```
A.searchsorted(B,side='right')-1
```

Sample run -

```
In [63]: A
Out[63]: array([  0.456,   2.   ,   2.948,   3.   ,   7.   ,  12.132])

In [64]: B
Out[64]: array([ 1.1,  1.9,  2.1,  5. ,  7. ])

In [65]: A.searchsorted(B,side='right')-1
Out[65]: array([0, 0, 1, 3, 4])

In [66]: A.searchsorted(A,side='right')-1 # With itself
Out[66]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Much faster on large arrays! Thank you!

Comment: @Davikar actually there is one bad edge case: if the last item of both arrays are the same value, the index returned is 0 (-1 without .clip(min=0).... so for example if you ran an array over itself like: ((A[:,None] > A).argmax(0)-1).clip(min=0) the result would be array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]), where the last item i would want would to be 5

Comment: This is great! Actually i originally was using side='left' expecting it to give me what i wanted but s='right' and subtracting 1 is exactly what i was hoping side='left' would do. The difference makes sense now... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this. np.argmax stops at the first True it encounters, so as long as A is sorted this provides the desired result.

```
[np.argmax(A>b)-1 for b in B]
```

Edit: I got the inequality wrong initially, it works now.

Comment: Thanks! Nice and concise. I will use your idea unless someone suggest an idea that's faster than iterating over elements of B. btw, If an element of B is smaller than the smallest element of A your loop returns index of -1, so i modified it to cap it at 0, which is what i would want: i = np.array([np.argmax(A>b)-1 for b in B]).clip(min=0)